# I want to fix the orientation of the keyboard

Tags: ios, objective-c, keyboard, uiinterfaceorientation

I want to fix the orientation of the keyboard.
My ViewController supports only Portrait.
If I rotate iPhone, the views in the ViewController does not rotate, but the keyboard appears in landscape.
I want to fix the portrait orientation of keyboard even if I rotate ViewController.

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotate
{
return NO;
}
```

This code does not work. I hear that UIWindow could be related..
Please give me how to solve this problem.

Comment: Are statusbar also rotated?

Answer (score 0):

Set in taget-> General Choose portrait only.

[image]